# Facebook replies empty array on API call for posts

Tags: facebook

I have a problem with API call on Facebook Graph API. This API call (with the php-sdk):

`$posts = $facebook->api('/me/posts?since=2010-1-1&until=2010-3-31T23:59:59');`

returns empty array, that looks like this using `var_dump` : `{ ["data"]=> array(0) { } }`

If I modify the call like this:

`$posts = $facebook->api('/me/posts?since=2010-1-1');`

it returns the right posts. If I modify it like this:

`$posts = $facebook->api('/me/posts?until=2010-3-31');`

It returns empty array again. However, this

`$posts = $facebook->api('/me/posts?until=2010-12-31');`

works fine (but for different posts, than I want).

All of the above, with "statuses" or "links" instead of "posts", return non-empty array.

What is going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are hitting infamous 5000 limit. Facebook acts like if you always have only latest 5000 records. So if your 5000th entry from top was newer than `2010-3-31` it won't return anything for `/me/posts?until=2010-3-31` query.

Run `/me/posts` query and look at the bottom item. Facebook won't return anything older than it no matter what extra query parameters you supply (undocumented feature).

Comment: Thanks for your idea.... but I don't post that much. It would mean I posted 5000 posts during the last 5 months, which counts for about 34 posts a day, which is way more than I post.

However, if all the "likes" and "comments" are counted, too, it can make sense.

Comment: @Karel run `/me/posts` and look at the bottom item. Facebook won't return anything older than it no matter what extra query parameters you supply.

Comment: @serg: oh, that's right (even the "previous" link, that is provided by facebook, doesn't return anything). Do you think it's a facebook bug? And where should I report it?

Comment: @Karel it's a feature that looks like a bug (and not documented anywhere). If you have time then report it, maybe they will do something about it finally (there probably already a few reports).

Comment: @serg is there any other place to report facebook bugs except the forum? edit: nevermind, I see the bugzilla

Comment: @serg: edit your answer to include your first comment and I will accept it